# Variable referenced before assignment in this code

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
try:
    connSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    connSock.connect((tgtHost, tgtPort))
except:
    pass
finally:
    connSock.close()
```

Pycharm says that:

> Local variable 'connSock' might be referenced before assignment on connSock.close() line

How is that even possible?

Am I missing something?

---

**UPDATE:**

socket() function may raise exception if your OS run out of descriptors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the `socket()` call on the second line raises an exception, then `connSock` is never bound.

Sockets can be used as context managers, use that to your advantage:

```
try:
    with socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) as connSock:
        connSock.connect((tgtHost, tgtPort))
except socket.error:
    pass
```

This'll close the socket when the `with` block is exited, without having to reference it, and only if the `socket()` call actually succeeded.

Note that you should **rarely** use a blanket `except: pass`. Better to catch specific exceptions.

Comment: when can that happen?

Comment: @Yetti: if the OS is out of descriptors, for example. PyCharm doesn't know how likely the chances are of `socket()` throwing an exception, just that it can happen.

Comment: @Yetti: if you don't expect an exception to be raised for `socket()` then *move it out of the `try..finally`*.

Comment: Thats exactly whats happening, Im opening too much sockets with different threads. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 3):

`socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)` might throw an exception, so that `connSock` never gets assigned. Then, `connSock.close()` can't possibly work.

Answer (score 1):

If the `try` block raises an error (specifically in the first line `connSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)`), `connSock` won't be defined when the `finally` block is executed.